# How do I round to the tenths position in C#?

Tags: c#, rounding

I am trying to understand how to round to the nearest tenths position with C#. For instance, I have a value that is of type double. This double is currently set to 10.75. However, I need to round and then truncate everything past the tenths position. In this case, I am seeking a value of 10.8. How do I round to the tenths position in C#?

Comment: Since you obviously know about math.round, it sounds like it's somehow not working for you.  Can you show what you tried and explain how it's different from what you expected?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
Math.Round(yourNumber, 1)
```

The second parameter is number of decimal places to round to. In your case you want 1 decimal place as an end result.

Answer (score 18):

You simply need to use the [overload of `Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx) that takes the `decimals` parameter.

```
Math.Round(10.75, 1) // returns 10.8
```

Just for comparison:

```
Math.Round(10.75)    // returns 11
Math.Round(10.75, 0) // returns 11
Math.Round(10.75, 2) // returns 10.75
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you Used `Math.Round()` in your title, I'm going to assume you've already tried the basic `Math.Round(10.75,1)` approach and it returns something you don't expect.  With that in mind, I suggest looking at some of the different overloads for the function, specifically one that accepts a `MidPointRounding` enum:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx

Comment: Very strange default behavior isn't "Standard Math behavior"

Comment: "Standard Math behavior" actually depends on context quite a bit for this.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to round it, or can you just format it for printing but allow the variable itself to hold its precision?  Something like:

```
decimal value = 10.75;
value.ToString ("#.#");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to "cut" everything after the first decimal, this shoudl work :

```
   return Math.Round(value * 10)/10
```