# Math rounding up

Tags: c#, rounding

I need some help with rounding 0.73 to 73 with `Math.Round()`. I am having troubles finding out how. Teacher wants me to make a method that takes in a decimal and return an integer.

Comment: double i = 0.73;
            double b = Math.Round( i);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.ReadKey();  I know i have to add something but i dont know what.

Comment: Why would you use `Round` instead of just multiplying by 100?

Comment: _rounding 0,73 to 73_ ? o.O That's **not** [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: Wait... and you want the result to be "73"? That isn't rounding, that would include a multiplication by 100 first.

Comment: Because it should work on random decimals. Multiplying with 100 wouldn't work with everything.

Comment: What you want is not rounding. Rounding 0.73 up would be 1 or 0.8.

Comment: use int result = (int)(0,73*100);

Comment: I know how to do that and I want to make it 73, teacher told that to me, via math.round(); .

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520990/1921715

Comment: Not what the teacher wants.

Comment: 0,73 -> 73 is not rounding. What does your teacher want "you" to do?

Comment: Make a method that takes in a decimal and return an integer

Comment: var result = Math.Round((0.73d * 100d), 0);
If you must use Math.Round, do you mean something like this?

Comment: "Make a method that takes in a decimal and return an integer", this isn't saying return 73, I'd imagine the teacher would expect you to return the nearest integer based on your rounding logic (0 or 1). What have you tried? We aren't here to do your homework

Comment: No you're not here to do my homework. I know the most logical thing is round it to 0 or 1...

Comment: Then why not do that? Has the teacher *specifically* stated that you need to return 73? That seems illogical

Comment: I have no idea, also waiting for a reply from him. Studying in a distance.

Comment: I would imagine they are looking for 0 or 1 (in this instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int Round(double number)
{
    int numberLenght = number.ToString().Length;
    int times = (int) Math.Pow(10, numberLenght-2);
    return (int) (number*times);
}
```

You something like this?

Comment: And if it is a negative number or represented in scientific format?